# How to use PHP closure with predefined arguments / parameters

Tags: php, closures

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
$x = 5;
$b = function ($x) {
    echo 'This should be 5 :' . $x;
};
function a($fn){
    echo 'In a ';
    $fn();
}
a($b);
```

That when you run this code, we get

> In a
>
> This should be 5 :5

What we get instead is

> Warning:  Missing argument 1 for {closure}(), called in
>   writecodeonline.com/php on line 10 and defined on line 3 This should
>   be 5

I don't want to redefine the argument I already defined

What I don't want neither is hide the $x. I don't want to change its visibility.

Is there a way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs: you can use the `use` expression for it:

```
$x = 5;

$b = function () use ($x) {
    echo 'This is x: ' . $x . "\n";
};

$b();

$c = function ($fn) {
    echo 'In c: ';
    $fn();
};

$c($b);
$x = 10;
$c($b);
```

Output:

```
This is x: 5
In c: This is x: 5
In c: This is x: 5
```

Note that despite the change of `$x` later the assigned value does not get changed. You can achieve that if you pass the variable by reference:

```
$x = 5;

$b = function () use (&$x) { // << Note the difference here
    echo 'This is x: ' . $x . "\n";
};

$b();

$c = function ($fn) {
    echo 'In c: ';
    $fn();
};

$c($b);
$x = 10;
$c($b);
```

Output:

```
This is x: 5
In c: This is x: 5
In c: This is x: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), `$x` cannot be automagically visible inside function `a()` unless you pass the argument into function `a()`

```
$x = 5;

$b = function ($x) {
    echo 'This should be 5 :' . $x;
};

function a($fn, $value) {
    echo 'In a ';
    $fn($value);
}

a($b, $x);
```

Comment: this would certainly work, but you make the microing of `$value` through your whole application to get it to work.

Comment: microing? If you need to pass an argument to your function `$b()`, then it must be passed to `$b()` at the point where `$b()` is called, not simply where it is defined. You're calling `$b()` from within function `a()`, so the argument must exist within the scope of `a()`